# Hexagon is distorting on x axis, when scaling on y globally

Tags: modeling

Here is screenshot :) Im making a circle with 6 sides, rotating it 30 degrees (z) and scaling it globally on y.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell this is expected behavior

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I'm really confused ?! is this the normal behavior ?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the screenshot, yes. I would need an animated GIF/video to be sure

Comment: just try it you'll see the object ( not just circle ) stretch along X and Y ( it's not global nor local Y really )

Comment: You should rotate the mesh in edit mode. While the object is rotated you and you scale on one axis you actually scaling in 2, you can see it in transform panel.

Comment: If you press `S` then `Y``Y` it will scale along the *local* Y axis and you will better see what is happening.

Comment: I don't think it should be the expected behaviour. I think this question explains it better https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249229/115533

Answer (score 4):

Here is why it stretch on the x axis : the scaling is done the world space (orientation ) and it gets projected to the local space of the object to be applied (since axis are not aligned world Y axis get projected on local X and Y axis) , the vertices has to keep their location the local space ( hence you see the distortion ) :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior. What is happening is you are scaling your mesh without having applied the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *Rotation*). When you apply the rotation to your mesh, this issue disappears.

[image]

Also moving the vertices in edit mode will prevent this issue.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Comment: @cegaton This might be a dup then?

Comment: how do i apply? i thought it was applied once i hit enter.

Comment: Ctrl+A in object mode and select Rotation from the menu