# How does blender scaling works?

Tags: python, transforms, matrix

I am new to blender. I have been looking into a github code, and trying to understand the operations.
I am confused about the blender scaling operation.

This is the code for scaling:

```
def __scale(self, name, size):
    obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
    for dim in range(3):
        obj.scale[dim] = size

def __ensureList(self, inp):
    if type(inp) != list:
        inp = [inp]
    return inp

def resize(self, names, size, dim=0):
    names = self.__ensureList(names)
    if type(names) == str:
        names = [names]
    for name in names:
        obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
        obj.dimensions[dim] = size
        scale = obj.scale[dim]
        self.__scale(name, scale)
```

To scale, I execute the following command:
`blender.resize([obj_name], 2.7)`

When I print the min, max and mean of the 3D points before and after scaling the results are:

before scaling:
`min_x: -0.20754599571228027, max_x: 0.20533299446105957, mean_x: 0.0007154246070189982`.
`min_y: -0.1282069981098175, max_y:  0.1692579984664917, mean_y:  0.0012065420240592241`.
`min_z: -0.46883198618888855, max_z:  0.3920080065727234, mean_z:  -0.000768613462913994`.

after scaling:
`min_x: -1.3572359085083008, max_x: 1.342764139175415, mean_x: 0.004678481022643731`
`min_y: -0.8384028077125549, max_y:1.1068536043167114, mean_y: 0.007890116447166636`
`min_z: -3.065901517868042, max_z: 2.5635154247283936, mean_z: -0.005026305425451572`

A scaling of 2.7 along each dimension is resulting into a scale of approx 6.55 along each dimension. Can someone please explain the math behind this scaling. I mean if there is a point X(x,y,z) before scaling then what would be X after scaling ?

I am asking this question as I am not able to understand the post: [How does scaling work in Blender, *exactly*?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51632/how-does-scaling-work-in-blender-exactly)

Thanks, and would appreciate any help in understanding this.

Some edits based on suggestions from the comments:

Min max mean are numpy.min(), numpy.max(), numpy.mean(). I loop over the mesh vertices (obj.data.vertices), and add the vertex.co to a numpy array. and the test object is a mesh.

Comment: Could you indicates how min/max are calculated here? using world matrix? What is the test object?

Comment: Min max mean are numpy.min(), numpy.max(), numpy.mean(). I loop over the mesh vertices (obj.data.vertices), and add the vertex.co to a numpy array.  and the test object is a mesh.

Comment: obj.data.vertices coordinates are not supposed to change when scaling... so are you using matrix_world?

Comment: ```bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)``` I do this before printining the vertices after applying scaling

Comment: OK, I think you should indicate all these in the question to make it understandable. Though, from the mesh you used where the 6.5 ratio comes from?

Comment: 6.55 is basically max_x (after scaling) / max_x (before scaling)

Comment: Yes... tried to reproduce your results. But failed. You should upload all the elements in a blend file. In first though, what you obtain is not expected (I think). So possibly, there is another reason.

Comment: can you explain how scaling works, I mean if there is a point X(x,y,z) before scaling then what would be X after scaling ? So if the scale is 2.7 would X after scaling be X*2.7 (x*2.7, y*2.7, z*2.7) ? Thanks !!

Comment: You are totally right. That's why I think there is another reason here (or I miss something). Upload a file, so that we can check that.

Comment: I am actually taking inspiration from this codebase: https://github.com/JannerM/intrinsics-network/blob/612e003fb6d15c075f6fbac8d7b26a357e7b99be/dataset/render.py#L95. What kind of file are you referring to ?

Comment: The blend file you are using for this test. Can upload it using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Was the object scaled before the script?